# Create a conditional variable by group and time and day over the panel data

Tags: postgresql, stata

I am trying to analyse connection between probability of call and distance to vehicles.

The example dataset ([here csv](https://github.com/lizardie/Stackexchange_Q3_stat)) looks like this:

```
id  day         time    called  d   
1   2009-06-24  1700    0       1037.6  
1   2009-06-24  1710    1       1191.9   
1   2009-06-24  1720    0       165.5
```

The real dataset has 10 million rows. There are `id`s that represent locations that called or not, in different time windows of (here) 10 minutes. 
I would like to first drop all rows with the same id that never called at this time at any date during the whole period.
Then I am left with rows that represent `id`s that called at some day during the analysis at the given time.

I would like to create a variable that at the row of the call has value of `0` and day before (or hour, week, month, whatever, but here day) at the same time it equals `-1` and day after `+1` etc. Later I would use that variable as input together with `called` and `distance` for analysis and comparison across different locations

I have looked for other answered questions but did not find something that fits. So answer or pointer to one would be appreciated. I am using Stata 13, but solving this with Postgres 9.3 or R would be welcome as well.

I shall need to repeat this procedure multiple times for several datasets, so ideally I would like to automatise as much as possible.

**Update**:

[Here is](https://github.com/lizardie/Stackexchange_Q3_stat/blob/master/test2result.csv) example of the desired result:

```
id  day         time    called  d  newvar   newvar2
1   2009-06-24  1700    0   1037.6  null    
1   2009-06-24  1710    1   1191.9  0        -2
1   2009-06-24  1720    0   165.5   -1  
1   2009-06-25  1700    0   526.7   null    
1   2009-06-25  1710    0   342.5   1        -1
1   2009-06-25  1720    1   416.1   0   
1   2009-06-26  1700    0   428.3   null    
1   2009-06-26  1710    1   240.7   2        0
1   2009-06-26  1720    0   228.7   1   
1   2009-06-27  1700    0   282.5   null    
1   2009-06-27  1710    0   182.1   3        1
1   2009-06-27  1720    0   195.5   2   
2   2009-06-24  1700    0   198.0   -1  
2   2009-06-24  1710    0   157.4   null    
2   2009-06-24  1720    0   234.9   null    
2   2009-06-25  1700    1   247.0   0
```

I added the `newvar2` because some locations might call several times at the given time window

Comment: please provide samples of wanted result

Comment: the desired result would be something like this :https://github.com/lizardie/Stackexchange_Q3_stat/blob/master/test2result.csv

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you try to do. maybe some sql you have so far?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking for a Stata solution, it is best to provide a data example using `dataex` (from SSC).

The problem is hard to visualize until the data is sorted by `id` and `time` (and further sorted by `day`). I did not convert the `day` variable to a Stata numeric date because, as constructed, the string sort order matches the natural date order.

You appear to want, for each call within a group of `id time`, the date offset in relation to the day of the call. This can be done by generating an order variable to track the index of the current observation within each `id time` group and then subtracting the index of the observation which makes the call.

Since you can have more than one call per time slot, you have to loop over the maximum number of calls in any given time slot in the data.

There's one difference with the results generated by this solution compared to yours: you seem to ignore the call on `2009-06-27` at `1710` for `id == 2`.

In the following example, the original data is presented sorted by `id time day` to provide the readers with a better intuition of what's going on.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte id str10 day int time byte called float distance str4 newvar byte newvar2
1 "2009-06-24" 1700 0 1037.6 "null"  .
1 "2009-06-25" 1700 0  526.7 "null"  .
1 "2009-06-26" 1700 0  428.3 "null"  .
1 "2009-06-27" 1700 0  282.5 "null"  .
1 "2009-06-24" 1710 1 1191.9 "0"    -2
1 "2009-06-25" 1710 0  342.5 "1"    -1
1 "2009-06-26" 1710 1  240.7 "2"     0
1 "2009-06-27" 1710 0  182.1 "3"     1
1 "2009-06-24" 1720 0  165.5 "-1"    .
1 "2009-06-25" 1720 1  416.1 "0"     .
1 "2009-06-26" 1720 0  228.7 "1"     .
1 "2009-06-27" 1720 0  195.5 "2"     .
2 "2009-06-24" 1700 0    198 "-1"    .
2 "2009-06-25" 1700 1    247 "0"     .
2 "2009-06-26" 1700 0  188.7 "1"     .
2 "2009-06-27" 1700 0  203.5 "2"     .
2 "2009-06-24" 1710 0  157.4 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-25" 1710 0  221.3 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-26" 1710 0  283.8 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-27" 1710 1   91.7 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-24" 1720 0  234.9 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-25" 1720 0  249.6 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-26" 1720 0  279.7 "null"  .
2 "2009-06-27" 1720 0  198.2 "null"  .
3 "2009-06-24" 1700 0  156.1 "-1"    .
3 "2009-06-25" 1700 1   19.9 "0"     .
3 "2009-06-26" 1700 0  195.2 "1"     .
3 "2009-06-27" 1700 0  306.2 "2"     .
3 "2009-06-24" 1710 0  150.1 "null"  .
3 "2009-06-25" 1710 0  163.7 "null"  .
3 "2009-06-26" 1710 0  288.2 "null"  .
3 "2009-06-27" 1710 0  311.7 "null"  .
3 "2009-06-24" 1720 0  135.1 "-2"    .
3 "2009-06-25" 1720 0    186 "-1"    .
3 "2009-06-26" 1720 1  297.2 "0"     .
3 "2009-06-27" 1720 0  375.9 "1"     .
end

* order observations by date within a id time group
sort id time day
by id time: gen order = _n

* number of calls at any given time
by id time: gen call = sum(called)

* repeat enough to cover the max number of calls per time
sum call, meanonly
local n = r(max)
forvalues i = 1/`n' {
    // the index of the called observation in the id time group
    by id time: gen index = order if called & call == `i'

    // replicate the index for all observations in the id time group
    by id time: egen gindex = total(index)

    // the relative position of each obs in groups with a call
    gen wanted`i' = order - gindex if gindex > 0

    drop index gindex
}

list, sepby(id time) noobs compress
```

and the results

```
. list, sepby(id time) noobs compress

  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | id          day   time   cal~d   dist~e   new~r   new~2   order   call   wan~1   wan~2 |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1   2009-06-24   1700       0   1037.6    null       .       1      0       .       . |
  |  1   2009-06-25   1700       0    526.7    null       .       2      0       .       . |
  |  1   2009-06-26   1700       0    428.3    null       .       3      0       .       . |
  |  1   2009-06-27   1700       0    282.5    null       .       4      0       .       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1   2009-06-24   1710       1   1191.9       0      -2       1      1       0      -2 |
  |  1   2009-06-25   1710       0    342.5       1      -1       2      1       1      -1 |
  |  1   2009-06-26   1710       1    240.7       2       0       3      2       2       0 |
  |  1   2009-06-27   1710       0    182.1       3       1       4      2       3       1 |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1   2009-06-24   1720       0    165.5      -1       .       1      0      -1       . |
  |  1   2009-06-25   1720       1    416.1       0       .       2      1       0       . |
  |  1   2009-06-26   1720       0    228.7       1       .       3      1       1       . |
  |  1   2009-06-27   1720       0    195.5       2       .       4      1       2       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  2   2009-06-24   1700       0      198      -1       .       1      0      -1       . |
  |  2   2009-06-25   1700       1      247       0       .       2      1       0       . |
  |  2   2009-06-26   1700       0    188.7       1       .       3      1       1       . |
  |  2   2009-06-27   1700       0    203.5       2       .       4      1       2       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  2   2009-06-24   1710       0    157.4    null       .       1      0      -3       . |
  |  2   2009-06-25   1710       0    221.3    null       .       2      0      -2       . |
  |  2   2009-06-26   1710       0    283.8    null       .       3      0      -1       . |
  |  2   2009-06-27   1710       1     91.7    null       .       4      1       0       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  2   2009-06-24   1720       0    234.9    null       .       1      0       .       . |
  |  2   2009-06-25   1720       0    249.6    null       .       2      0       .       . |
  |  2   2009-06-26   1720       0    279.7    null       .       3      0       .       . |
  |  2   2009-06-27   1720       0    198.2    null       .       4      0       .       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  3   2009-06-24   1700       0    156.1      -1       .       1      0      -1       . |
  |  3   2009-06-25   1700       1     19.9       0       .       2      1       0       . |
  |  3   2009-06-26   1700       0    195.2       1       .       3      1       1       . |
  |  3   2009-06-27   1700       0    306.2       2       .       4      1       2       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  3   2009-06-24   1710       0    150.1    null       .       1      0       .       . |
  |  3   2009-06-25   1710       0    163.7    null       .       2      0       .       . |
  |  3   2009-06-26   1710       0    288.2    null       .       3      0       .       . |
  |  3   2009-06-27   1710       0    311.7    null       .       4      0       .       . |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  3   2009-06-24   1720       0    135.1      -2       .       1      0      -2       . |
  |  3   2009-06-25   1720       0      186      -1       .       2      0      -1       . |
  |  3   2009-06-26   1720       1    297.2       0       .       3      1       0       . |
  |  3   2009-06-27   1720       0    375.9       1       .       4      1       1       . |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It works thanks. I am checking this on the big set.

I suppose that here: 

        `** running number of calls at any given time`
        `by id time: gen call = sum(called)`

you meant 'running number of calls at any time' rather than number of calls which would be this:

        `** total number of calls at any time`
        `bysort id time: egen call_cnt=total(called)`

It does not affect the result though. And I missed the call on 2009-06-07 at 1710 by 2.

Comment: You cannot substitute the running sum with a `egen total()` call; the running sum is used to number each call and is used to target each call in the loop when determining the index of the call. This does affect the results, even in the example posted. See the case where there is two calls.